# How to find brightest spot in a 2D array of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, point, light

I'm trying to figure out how to go about using these methods to complete this assignment but I'm still relatively new with Java and don't know where to go with it. The array file we have is: [2D Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNHNg.png)

Here is the assignment: [Assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UX8q.png)

I am just looking for some insight on the math and what to use to get started with these methods. I'm not asking for anyone to do my homework! Thanks for any help in advance!

Here is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    File skyimage = new File("skyimage.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(skyimage);

    int r, c;

    r = scan.nextInt();
    c = scan.nextInt();

    int sky[][] = new int[r][c];


    for(r = 0; r < sky.length; r++){
        for(c = 0; c < sky[r].length; c++)
            sky[r][c] = scan.nextInt();
        }


    printArray(sky);
    lightSource(sky, c);


}//end main



private static void printArray(int[][] sky) {

    for(int r = 0; r < sky.length; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < sky[r].length; c++){
            System.out.printf("%5d", sky[r][c]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}


public static void lightSource(int sky[][], int n){
    Point[] lightPoint = new Point[n];

    for(int r = 0; r < sky.length; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < sky[r].length; c++){
            new Point(r, c);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The brightest interior point is located at: " + lightPoint);

}//end method



public static void darkSource(){

}//end method



public static void filterImage(){

}//end method



public static void negativeImage(){

}//end method
```

Comment: Well it seems you need a way to define which neighbors are available (at least 3 if you are a Pixel in the corner, at most 9 if you are surrounded)... Once you get the neighbors, you add their values and keep the <x,y> position and the value if and only if is greater (or lesser, depending which comparison you are doing) to your previous "point"

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was thinking. So I'll need a for loop with a nested if statement? If it's greater, it will store the value, it less it will run the next point?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have read the input, all you need is just a few utility methods
(like `sum`, `getNeighbours` and `isValidPoint`) and a few loops.

Here is a sketch (not a full-blown solution).
In it I have hard-coded the sample `sky` input.

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test045 {

    private static int[][] sky = {
        {10,2,2},
        {10,5,1},
        {1,2,2}
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point min = null;
        Point max = null;
        Integer sumMin = null;
        Integer sumMax = null;
        Integer s = null;
        for (int i=0; i<sky.length; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<sky[0].length; j++){
                s=sum(getNeighbours(i, j));

                if (sumMin==null || sumMin > s){
                    min = new Point(i,j);
                    sumMin = s;
                }

                if (sumMax==null || sumMax < s){
                    max = new Point(i,j);
                    sumMax = s;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Max Light at: " + max.x + ", " + max.y + 
                           " ; MAX Light = " + sumMax);
        System.out.println("Min Light at: " + min.x + ", " + min.y + 
                           " ; MIN Light = " + sumMin);
    }

    private static int sum(List<Point> lst){
        int sum = 0;
        for (Point p : lst){
            sum += sky[p.x][p.y];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    private static List<Point> getNeighbours(int ip, int jp){
        List<Point> lst = new ArrayList<Point>();
        for (int i=-1; i<=1; i++){
            for (int j=-1; j<=1; j++){
                if (isValidPoint(ip+i, jp+j)){
                    lst.add(new Point(ip+i, jp+j));
                }
            }
        }
        return lst;
    }

    private static boolean isValidPoint(int i, int j){
        return 
            i >= 0 && i < sky.length &&
            j >= 0 && j < sky[0].length;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Got everything working properly.. Now I just need to write the methods for the filter and the negative. Do you have any suggestion on how to do the negative? Is there something in java that I can use to turn a number between 0-1024 to its opposite?

Comment: Just realized it'd be a simple "subtract itself from 1024" to get the opposite